# Hide and show a usercontrol placed inside a usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two user controls(A & B) placed on a particular user control(C). I want these control to come up or show only when button is clicked. I bound the visibility of A and B controls to properties but of no use. I applied styles also to hide/show but again no success.

Also I want usercontrol C to be stretched if in case both A and B controls are not visible.
*Here is the usercontrol xaml where main datacontext is RunViewModelObject*

```
<UserControl>
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="RTMLOVPanel">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LovPaneVisible, ElementName=RtmLovView, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="AttachmentPanel">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AttachmentsPaneVisible, ElementName=AttachmentsView, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="RtmLovTemplate" x:Name="RtmLovView">
            <Shared:SidePaneView_RtmLov/>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="AttachmentsTemplate" x:Name="AttachmentsView">
            <Shared:SidePaneView_Attachments/>
        </ControlTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RunViewModelObject}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=RtmLovTemplate}" 
                DataContext="{Binding LovObject}" Style="{DynamicResource RTMLOVPanel}" />

        <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AttachmentsTemplate}"
                DataContext="{Binding AttachmentsObject}" Style="{DynamicResource AttachmentPanel}" />

        <Grid Grid.Column="1"  >
            <ContentControl x:Name="CCRunView" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded" Unloaded="UserControl_Unloaded" >                
                <ContentControl.Content>
                    <UC:UCDynamicRunForm Visibility="{Binding DataSourceControlVisibility, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToOppositeVisibilityConverter}}" DataContext="{Binding UCDynamicFormVMObject}"/>
                </ContentControl.Content>
            </ContentControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's almost impossible to know what's wrong. Add some code samples to your question.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with Bindings or Styles in UserControls inside UserControls. That's a usual practice. But you have to keep track of the DataContext, since controls A and B will inherit C's DataContext, by default.

Comment: almulo, i have updated the sample. Please look into the one.

Comment: `Collapsed` instead of `Hidden` might help to make C take up the space from `A` and `B`.

Comment: @user1910087 You're using `ElementName` with the names of the ControlTemplates, and that's never gonna work. I don't even understand what you're trying to do there... If `AttachmentsPaneVisible` is a property of `AttachmentsObject`, then you don't need that `ElementName` at all and it should work if you remove it.

Comment: My problem here is "Attachmentobject" is residing inside "RunViewModelObject". I want my attachmentobject view to come upfront. But its unable to do so. AttachmentPaneVisible property is inside RunViewModelObject. Even if i Raise Property the control does not appear.